# NSManagedObjectContext -save: causing SIGSEGV crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm seeing several crash reports for my app with the same Core Data stack trace:

[image]

I've been unable to reproduce this crash, but I'm thinking it has something to do with cascading deletes of `NSManagedObject` relationships. That's judging by the call to `_propagatePendingDeletesAtEndOfEvent:` seen in the stack trace. My `NSManagedObjectContext` is set up as follows:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext == nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing calls to `-save:` to crash with this stack trace throughout my app?

Comment: looks like a data race..

Answer (score 5):

From the stack trace I can only see that it is a race condition, more specifically a data race on a `strong` property or variable, probably in a dictionary. Since the crash is happening on the main thread, my first guess would be that you used an API on a background thread that should not be accessed on a background thread.

- Why do I think it's a data race?
- What's the most likely reason for core data code to crash on the main thread because of a race condition?
- A few suggestions for fixing this bug.

## Why do I think it's a data race?

Because the crash happens in `objc_retain`. This is just experience. In 9 out of 10 cases where I see a crash from retaining an object, it's because of a data race. In the one other case, the culprit was manually memory management done wrong. If you are interested in more detail, you may look up the sources of objc_storeStrong().

Second, the [Concurrency section in the Core Data Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) has this interesting piece of information:

> NSMainQueueConcurrencyType is specifically for use with your application interface and can only be used on the main queue of an application.
>
> The NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType configuration creates its own queue upon initialization and can be used only on that queue. Because the queue is private and internal to the NSManagedObjectContext instance, it can only be accessed through the performBlock: and the performBlockAndWait: methods.

## What's the most likely reason for core data code to crash on the main thread because of a race condition?

According to the code in your question you are using the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, so core data should not be used on a background queue with this "managed context".

My guess is that you are calling core data APIs from a backgroud thread somewhere.

## A few suggestions for fixing this bug.

A race condition does not always result in a crash. For this reason, such crashes can sometimes not be reproduced easily. All is not lost, however.

To see if it is indeed a data race, you have to look at the complete crash report. With the crash report, you don't only get a backtrace of the crashing main thread, you also get a backtrace of all other threads of the process, at the time where the crash occured. (Just search for "CoreData" in the crash report.) If you are very unlucky, there are no core data APIs visible on any background thread. You should see at least one thread that has some "autorelasepoolpop"-frames in this case though. If you found some "CoreData" frames on a background stack trace, find the frames in that stack trace that point to your apps code. There you have the culprit.

For debugging, you may put a few `assert([NSThread isMainThread]);` calls all over the place, wherever you call core data APIs. If it crashes because of an assertion failure, you know where the problem is.

If you are using Xcode 9, you may want to try out the new "Main Thread Sanitizer" (in the scheme settings under "Diagnostics", in the same panel where the "Thread Sanitizer" is also configured. You may want to "pause on issues"). If this doesn't help, also try the "Thread Sanitizer".

You may also switch the concurrency type to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. Be sure to wrap all core data API calls with `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` calls, otherwise you will not get less crashes but much more crashes. This is the way to go if you really need to be using core data from a background queue, e.g. for performance reasons.

If you are lucky, this is just a tiny code mistake somewhere and can be fixed in 10minutes :-) . If you are very unlucky, the concurrency architecture of the app is broken and you have to (re)design it :-/ .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I'll look into these suggestions.